# Variable inside componentDidMount are undefined using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have the following block of code:

```
const UserNotification = ({ user }) => {
  const url = `https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/${user.channel}/feeds.json?&dynamic=true`;
  console.log(url); //https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/594944/feeds.json?&dynamic=true OK
  return <UserNoti url = { url } />
}

class UserNoti extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json,
        });
      });
  }
 render() {...}}
```

However, I get a  `'url' is not defined  no-undef`  for the following line: `fetch(url)` in `componentDidMount()`. How can I call url variable inside componentDidMount method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.props.url` to access `url` propery you pass to `UserNoti` class.

```
componentDidMount() {
   fetch(this.props.url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json,
       });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `UserNotification` you pass `url` as a component prop. With ES6 class components, props are accessed using `this.props.propName`. So, in your case, you should do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(this.props.url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        items: json,
      });
    });
}
```

More info from the official React documentation on [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).